# Google Scripts - Compare Color & Change Font Color

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to compare data from two different columns and when they don't match I want the data in column 6 to turn Red and if it is changed back to match it turns back to black.

I don't want to use to conditional formating from the menue because I dont want people to be able to turn it off.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet      = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var col        = activeCell.getColumn();
  var row        = activeCell.getRow();
  var col6       = activeCell.getColumn( col == 6 && row >=5 && row <=55 && sheet);
  var col14      = activeCell.getColumn( col == 14 && row >=5 && row <=55 && sheet);
  var first      = get.Value(col6);
  var second     = get.Value(col14);
                  
  
  //Start Time Function
 if (col == 1 && row>=5 && row<=55 && sheet.getRange(row,col).getValue() == ""){ 
    sheet.getRange(row,1,1,sheet.getMaxColumns()).clearContent(); 
  }
    else if (col == 1){
    sheet.getRange(row,col+11).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('hh:mm:ss');
    sheet.getRange(row,col+13).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('hhmm');
    sheet.getRange(row,col+5).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('hhmm');
    sheet.getRange(row,col+3).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat();    
   }  
     
  //End Time Function
   if (col == 8 && row>=5 && row<=55 && sheet.getRange(row,col).getValue() == ""){ 
    sheet.getRange(row,7,1).clearContent() && sheet.getRange(row,13,1).clearContent() && sheet.getRange(row,15,1).clearContent();
   }
  else if (col == 8) {
    sheet.getRange(row,col+5).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('hh:mm:ss');
    sheet.getRange(row,col+7).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('hhmm');
    sheet.getRange(row,col-1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('hhmm');   
  }
  
  // Data Valadation Start Time
  // Confirm data in column 6 matches column 14, if different set column 6 font to red.
 
    if(first != second){
      var cell = sheet.getRange(first);
      cell.setFontColor("red");  
    }
    else if(first == second){
      var cell = sheet.sheet.getRange(first);
      cell.setFontColor("black");
    }
   
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. What is the question?

Comment: Rubén I cannot get the data in column 6 to turn red when it doesn't equal the data in column 14. Can you tell me why it might not be working?

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. What is your current issue of the script? 2. What are `get.Value(col6)` and `get.Value(col14)`?

Comment: Hey Tanika, the issue is that my last if statement doesn't turn the font to red when it doesn't match. `get.Value(col6)` & `get.Value(col14)` are supposed to be getting the value of the cells that need to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Be careful not to mix up ranges and values
- Also, you seem to use methods methods that do not exist in Apps Script / cannot be used with parameters

  - Please check the documentation for [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and [getColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getcolumn)

**A modified working sample based on your code:**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var sheet      = e.range.getSheet();
  var col        = activeCell.getColumn();
  var row        = activeCell.getRow();
  var first      =   sheet.getRange(row, 6); 
  var second     =   sheet.getRange(row, 14);
  
  if(first.getValue() != second.getValue()){
    var cell = first;
    cell.setFontColor("red");  
  }
  else {
    var cell = first;
    cell.setFontColor("black");
  }  
}
```

Comment: You got me going in the right direction. It's taken me a little time to get it fully working. I was having trouble with the 'first' column turning red when inputing the end time data.I fixed the problem by adding an additional formatting rule changing my times to plain text. I'll post my code below for everyone to see.

Answer (score 1):

Working Code.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet      = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var col        = activeCell.getColumn();
  var row        = activeCell.getRow();
                
  
//Start Time Function
 if (col == 1 && row>=5 && row<=55 && sheet.getRange(row,col).getValue() == ""){ 
    sheet.getRange(row,1,1,sheet.getMaxColumns()).clearContent();
 
  }
    else if (col == 1){
    sheet.getRange(row,12,1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('hh:mm:ss'); //real time
    sheet.getRange(row,14,1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('hhmm').setNumberFormat("@");
    sheet.getRange(row,6,1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('hhmm').setNumberFormat("@");
    sheet.getRange(row,4,1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat();  //Date Row    
   } // END - Start Time Function
  
     
//End Time Function
   if (col == 8 && row>=5 && row<=55 && sheet.getRange(row,col).getValue() == ""){ 
    sheet.getRange(row,7,1).clearContent() && sheet.getRange(row,13,1).clearContent() && sheet.getRange(row,15,1).clearContent();
     
   }
  else if (col == 8) {
    sheet.getRange(row,13,1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('hh:mm:ss'); // real time
    sheet.getRange(row,15,1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('hhmm').setNumberFormat("@");
    sheet.getRange(row,7,1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('hhmm').setNumberFormat("@");
    
  } // END - End Time Function
  
  
// Data Valadation - Start Time
  var firstF      =   sheet.getRange(row,6,1); 
  var secondN     =   sheet.getRange(row,14,1);
  
  if(firstF.getValue() != secondN.getValue()){
    var cell = firstF;
    cell.setFontColor("red");  
  }
  else {
    var cell = firstF;
    cell.setFontColor("black");
  } // END - Data Valadation - Start Time
   
  
// Data Valadation - End Time
  var firstG      =   sheet.getRange(row,7,1); 
  var secondO     =   sheet.getRange(row,15,1);
  
  if(firstG.getValue() != secondO.getValue()){
    var cell = firstG;
    cell.setFontColor("red");  
  }
  else {
    var cell = firstG;
    cell.setFontColor("black");
  } // END - Data Valadation - End Time 
  
  
  
  } // END - function onEdit
```